# angular2 reports error when I use other class which is in another typescript-file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I import a class which is in another file, the angular2 can't pass the compiling. But if I copy the class to the same file, it can pass the compiling.

The error info is as follow:

> /Users/SranLiu/Documents/code/angular/training-tracker/src/app/exercise-detail.component.ts
>   (8,2): Type '{ id: number; name: string; exerciseSets: { id: number;
>   num: number; previousWeight: number; weig...' is not assignable to
>   type 'Exercise'.   Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and 'exerciseSets' does not exist in type 'Exercise'.

[screenshot of error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Tkg.jpg)

And the code is as follow:

First file:

```
//exercise-detail.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Exercise } from './exercise';


let exercise: Exercise = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'bench press',
    exerciseSets: [{
        id: 1,
        num: 1,
        previousWeight: 0,
        weight: 10,
        reps: 12,
        isFinish: true
    },{
        id: 2,
        num: 2,
        previousWeight: 0,
        weight: 10,
        reps: 12,
        isFinish: false
    }]
};

@Component({
    selector: 'exercise-detail',
    template: `
       <table border='1'>
           <tr>
               <td>finish?</td>
               <td>{{exercise.exerciseSets[1].isFinish}}</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    `
})
export class ExerciseDetailComponent {

    exercise = exercise;
}
```

Second file:

```
//exercise.ts
export class ExerciseSet {
    id: number;
    num: number;
    previousWeight: number;
    weight: number;
    reps: number;
    isFinish: boolean;
}

export class Exercise {

    id: number;
    name: string;
    exerciseSets: ExerciseSet[];
}
```

If I copy the class from second file to the first file as follows, it can pass the compiling and run successfully.

```
//exercise-detail.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class ExerciseSet {
    id: number;
    num: number;
    previousWeight: number;
    weight: number;
    reps: number;
    isFinish: boolean;
}

export class Exercise {

    id: number;
    name: string;
    exerciseSets: ExerciseSet[];
}

let exercise: Exercise = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'bench press',
    exerciseSets: [{
        id: 1,
        num: 1,
        previousWeight: 0,
        weight: 10,
        reps: 12,
        isFinish: true
    },{
        id: 2,
        num: 2,
        previousWeight: 0,
        weight: 10,
        reps: 12,
        isFinish: false
    }]
};

@Component({
    selector: 'exercise-detail',
    template: `
       <table border='1'>
           <tr>
               <td>finish?</td>
               <td>{{exercise.exerciseSets[1].isFinish}}</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    `
})
export class ExerciseDetailComponent {

    exercise = exercise;
}
```

I think this problem is not because of the grammar and logic. Maybe I missed some rule in typescript or angular, like if I will use the class in another file, I need declare or something. I only use the typescript only few days, so does anyone have idea?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Note however, that `Exercise`, and `ExerciseSet` should not be declared as classes but rather as interfaces. This is just a recommendation as it can cause subtle bugs. Your code is perfectly valid, just not optimal.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. I found I made a really stupid mistake. Now I solved it.

Comment: What was it? Please post, or update your question because, as it stands this is confusing.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I post my answer bellow. I think I made a really stupid mistake. lol

Answer (score 0):

If you use "npm start" to make your project compile automatically, you maybe meet a similar problem as me. Because the npm seems to only support compiling existed files, if you create a new file during the npm work, npm can't scan the new file.

So I use "ng start" to recomplie the project manually, then my project can work again.

Comment: `npm start` is just an alias for a command defined in your **package.json** file. You can customize it to run whatever you want.